# Error while saving new contribution

Tags: contributions, joomla, php

I have recently migrated my CiviCRM installation from one server to another server. 
Now facing an issue in saving new contribution. If I save the contribution without checked "Send Receipt?" it will be saved  properly. If I checked this "Send Receipt?" option it will give me an error.

Error : CiviCRM-001 - An error has occurred.

[image]

Comment: Is this in Joomla? Are you certain that directory exists? Can you send an email through the cms? (For example try creating a system email such as by creating a new article.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the utility "wkhtmltopdf" was not found at the expected location. This is configured at Administer -> System Settings -> Misc (/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1), "Path to wkhtmltopdf executable".

You will need to find whether this utility is installed on the new server and if so, enter the full path to the wkhtmltopdf executable. If it's not installed, you can leave this field blank and CiviCRM will use the default PDF generation method instead. However this has performance issues and may cause errors from exceeding PHP memory limit or timeout.

If you don't actually need a PDF copy of receipts, you can disable this with the "Attach PDF copy to receipts" setting on the same form.

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: Its working now. I got mail Donation Receipt my mail but in mail some warning also there :
Warning: Smarty error: [in string:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> some more  HTML tags and a file path also there.
/home/<domain>/www/<site>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094